# How to restore session in SQL database using C#?

Tags: c#, sql

```
// <span class="code-SummaryComment"><summary>
</span>/// Student Class
/// <span class="code-SummaryComment"></summary>
</span>[Serializable]
internal sealed class Student
{
   public int Roll { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Bio { get; set; }
}

 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
 {
sb.Append("Compression Enabled Session Demo");
 }
Student student = new Student { Roll = 1, Name = "Abhijit Jana", Bio = sb.ToString() ;
Session["Info"] = student;
```

i store this data in session object.
but how can i store this session in database and access this session from another application.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to know.??

Comment: If you thinking about object serialization to database, you shouldn't. You should use some kind of [Object-relational mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) or write SQL yourself